# How to set label for Yii2 Captcha widget?

Tags: php, yii2

Using Yii2, I realise that the template property for a [CAPTCHA Widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-captcha-captcha.html#$template-detail) only has an `{image}` and `{input}` token. My question is, How do I actually set the `{label}` token via the template property and move it around, so maybe I want it under the `{image}` for example?

I have tried the following: (setting the label inside the `field` like you would an ordinary form field).

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode', ['template' => '{label}'])->widget(Captcha::className(), [
    'template' => '<div class="col-xs-12">{image}</div><div class="col-xs-12">{input}</div>',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'CAPTCHA Code', 'class' => 'form-control']
]) ?>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You can add label after `<?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode', ['template' => '{label}'])->widget(Captcha::className(), [
    ...
])->label('text') ?>`

Comment: You answered my question. I realised though that I did not explain myself properly and was actually more after how to move the {label} around, so maybe I want it under the image for example.

Comment: you have to use css for that.

Comment: Ahh wow, is that it, is that a limitation of the widget in Yii2 ATM? Or does it make sense to you? Sorry not sure how to make your comment as an answer.

Comment: probably, that's my limitation for widget, not sure about yii2.

Comment: `['template' => '{label} {image} {input}']` this part plays the role actually. try changing the order around for example `{image} {label} {input}` then you will get image first, then label then input.

and of course you can do it with css as well, once you know how the elements are structured

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'captcha')->widget(\yii\captcha\Captcha::classname(),['options' => [
                     'placeholder' => 'Please enter the letters displayed above'
                        , 'Class' => 'form-control'
                        , 'style' => 'Top-margin: 10px;'
                ]])->label('Security Code')?>
```